# @ Char is on the Wrong Position in German Layout

Tags: macos, keyboard

I've a strange Problem with my new Mac. During the Install i've used a Windows Keyboard, after the Install Process was completed i've switched my Keyboard to Apple Magic Keyboard.

But now i can't use the original Keymap for the Keyboard. At Example if i press alt+q it will draw an @ char. How can i change it back, so that the @ Char will be printed if alt+l is pressed?

The Keyboard Layout in Settings is set to German, i've also tried to change it from German to German (Default) back. But this take no effect.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Anything else besides @ not in the right place?

Comment: I don't see anything called "German (Default)" in Input Sources.  If you try to add a German keyboard by using the + button, you should see German, German Standard, Austrian, ABC Qwertz, and Swiss German.  What do you see?

Comment: I'will test if there's another key whos on the wrong place. 

Sorry, i mean German Standard. 

I will Upload the Picture later, if i'll be back at the Mac.

Comment: If you have ONLY ONE ITEM  on the Input Sources list, and that item is called German, Austrian, or ABC Qwertz, you will have @ on Option L.  If the only item is called German Standard, you will have @ on Option Q.  If the only item is called Swiss German, you will have @ on Option G.  Let us know what you get when those are the only items on the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try adding "Austrian" in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Input Sources** and see if that works.

Then use that or try removing "German" and adding it again.

Comment: Thats solved the Problem. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources and add a new input source (using the plus button in the bottom left)

Choose an input source that matches what you want. Hold down the alt button to see what alt + the keys would produce.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a German keyboard, go to system preferences > keyboard > input sources and make sure the only item there is called German (and NOT German Standard)

If you are not using German, tell us what language your keyboard is.

Comment: The Settings are correct. I'm using German as Input Source. 

But this do not solve my problem ....

Comment: @0xS74CK Please edit your question to include a picture of your Input Sources preference pane, as it really should not be possible to get @ at option Q with "German" as the only item on the list.  Only German Standard does this.